Active Directory restrict log on to with OpenVPN clients fails
We have an OpenVPN server and Active Directory. I'd like to restrict certain VPN users to only be able to log on to a couple machines. I tried to accomplish this using Log On To in the AD Account tab. After I configured the machines, the user can no longer connect via OpenVPN. I don't even see his attempts in the logs.
So, I went back to Log On To and added the vpn server's inside address (no go), the outside address (no go), both AD servers (no go) to no avail. These servers should be the only ones in the login path. Not sure where to look to find out what other hosts might be involved in the process in order to allow the user to even connect, let alone try to connect to the machines I want him to.
If I must continue to add servers just to get him able to log in, this additional access to servers concerns me. Has anyone else gotten this configuration to work?
Maybe I need to forgo using Log On To in AD and restrict his access through GPO?

"Logon to workstations" restriction should work at initial domain logon. But if the client VPN software connects after desktop is retrieved, the restriction should apply in the second logon provided that logoff does not disconnect client VPN. If logoff process disconnects the user from  VPN then there is no chance that the  domain logon would trigger the "only allow logon from these workstations".
If logoff process does not disconnect the user from VPN, there will still be DC connection at domain logon time, hence the restriction should apply.
You may try to test a network logon after interactive domain logon instead of an interactive logon to verify that the restriction is applied. The workstation list should contain the names of domain-joined clients.
